# Конвертация svg изображений в PNG или JPEG

Tags: linux, svg, png, jpeg

Имеется большое количество SVG изображений.
Необходимо их конвертировать в PNG или JPEG.
Что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Imagemagick, inkscape: оба умеют из командной строки изображения конвертировать

Answer (score 1):

Используйте замечательный пакет Inkscape, который имеет опции импорта/экспорта изображений. На сегодняшний день это самый лучший рендер, который вы сможете найти. Просто запустите `inkscape --help` и погрузитесь в мир удивительных возможностей, которые дает эта прекрасная программа.

Конечно, есть и другой вариант: вы устанавливаете Chrome и на HTML5, при помощи тега `Canvas`, отрисовываете все изображения. Ставить софт совершенно не нужно, можно использовать посетителей сайта как распределенный ботнет для вычислений и рендера, что в мире победившего HTML5 является отличной практикой и доступно каждому желающему!

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать PNG. JPEG предназначен только для фотографий. Как-то так:

```
for f in *.svg ; do convert -background transparent -density 1000 "$f" "${f%svg}png" ; done
```

Детально о всех параметрах написано тут: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

Но вообще, SVG это такой формат, который лучше по возможности использовать как есть. Вы можете очень сильно потерять как в качестве, так и в объёме при конвертировании вектора в растр.